# Help me to determine absolute encoder parameters

Tags: encoder

I see [this encoder](https://www.sick.com/media/pdf/3/73/273/dataSheet_SRM50-HFA0-K22_1037072_en.pdf) on the internet (SRM50-HFA0.)

I need to know:

1. What is the difference between "sine/cosine periods per revolution" and "number of the absolute ascertainable revolutions?"
2. What are the "total number of steps"/"integral non-linearity" and "differential non-linearity?"
3. Are the "REFSIN" and "REFCOS" signals -SIN and -COS signals?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the essential details from the datasheet (including the brand and part number) so we don't have to follow a link to know what it is and the question will make sense if the link dies.

Comment: Thank you, I have uploaded pictures of the datasheet as well.

Comment: I've used some of Sick's programmable incremental encoders (handy, as it can act as a spare for many different types) but I haven't seen this one. It looks like they're able to give out 1024 sine/cosine cycles for one revolution! Meanwhile they're tracking the revolutions and able to count up to 4096. Good question. There are a couple of Sick videos on YouTube but I can't find this model but some have extensive gear chains in the back.

Comment: read about hiperface , first: https://cdn.sick.com/media/docs/5/65/865/Operating_instructions_Specification_Hiperface%C2%AE_Motor_feedback_protocol_en_IM0064865.PDF

Answer (score 2):

***sin/cos periods per revolution***, means you get an output signal like depicted X 1024 times = 1 revolution of encoder, or vice versa the depicted signal trace equals to 1/1024-th rev's movement.

If you transform sin/cos signals into quadrature pulses, you then get 1024 pulses per revolution.

***total number of steps***, 4096 revolutions X 1024 sin/cos periods per revolution X 32 possibly the extrapolated positions within one sin/cos period, this number depends on ADC and used MCU/DSP.

EDIT:

***total number of steps***, 4096 revolutions X 32768 steps/turn

[image]

> Are the "REFSIN" and "REFCOS" signals -SIN and -Cos signals?

Yes. See the Hiperface documentation.

> What is the difference between "sine/cosine periods per revolution"
> and "number of the absolute ascertainable revolutions?"

sin/cos periods determine the position within one revolution, meanwhile there is yet another type of encoder embedded for multi turn. Usually a gearbox with a coded disk and hall sensors that do measure number of revolutions, similar like water meter.

Picture taken [here](http://gaseswiki.com/index.php?title=Absolute_Encoders)
[image]

Some encoders use just a built in battery to store the absolute position, without a coded disk - in your case that would make sense